# Custom QuickCheck failed message

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

```
test1 = hspec $ do
  describe "blabla" $ do
    it "should be equl" $ verbose $
      \input-> ...
```

In the above code, when a test failed, it prints the failed `input`. But I'm actually interested in another value that can be calculated from `input`. Can I ask `QuickCheck` to print the other value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow I've never seen it advertised, but you can use `hspec`s expectations inside of `QuickCheck` properties. Here is an example:

```hs
  describe "blabla" $ do
    it "should be equl" $ verbose $ \input ->
      round input `shouldBe` floor (input :: Double)
```

Above property is clearly not true, so it should fail. Since we are not only interested `input`, but also want to know the computed values from it, `shouldBe` will give us just that:

```
  3) blabla should be equl
       Falsifiable (after 2 tests and 4 shrinks):
         0.6
       expected: 0
        but got: 1
```

Naturally, due to `verbose`, only `input` will be printed for passing tests, while computed value (eg. `round input`) will only be printed for a failed test case, which is what you were looking for it seems anyways.